# instagram API 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, curl, instagram-api, html-framework-7

I have been searching a loooot for some good answers and havent been so lucky.

I will explain for you my issue. I have made an web-app API with Instagram and it works fine.

But then I wanted to take it further and started making an "ios app" with it based on the Framework7. But now I have an issue that I havent been able to solve and I dont know what to do.

The problem is that when I get a response from instagram it works, but when I want to click on a link or picture that comes from instagram I have an issue. And the issue is this:

--->
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http...' is therefore not allowed access.

I have been searching I have found some things like cURL and then that Instagram has something called "X-Insta-Forwarded-For header".

My app is made on javascript/jquery.

Please help me. I know I havent give you enough information but tell me what you might need so I can give you that and help me out to get through this issue that is huge pain.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your ajax request using dataType: jsonp?

Comment: yes it is..
This is the ajax request:
     $.ajax ({
           url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=" + posLat + "&lng=" + posLng + "&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN", dataType: 'jsonp', cache: false });
        }

@Likwid_T